# Video playing in Android tablet

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, media-player

I want to play a large video using HTTP on an Android tablet.

I don't want to save that viedo on the device. That is, if the large video data received by the web service is in little chunks, I don't want to save that binary data and later play the video. I want play the video as it downloads.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Simply encode the video using FFMPEG and then use the qt-faststart tool to enable streaming. I use a command like this to encode videos for android phones

```
$ ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 -s 480x320 -threads 4 -vcodec libx264 -flags +loop+mv4 -cmp 256 -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -subq 5 -trellis 1 -refs 5 -bf 0 -flags2 +mixed_refs -coder 0 -me_range 16 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qmin 15 -qmax 20 -qdiff 5 -b 700k -r 600 -acodec libfaac -ar 48000 -ab 48000 -pass 1 outfile.mp4
```

My code will be kind of Low Quality for tablets. So, experiment by changing the resolution, bitrate etc.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is called **buffering**.

You can read the tutorial *[Media Playback](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)*. Basically you will need the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class, and then set the URL of your video as the data source, and MediaPlayer would do all the complicated stuff.